# MySQL PreparedStatement addBatch does not run as a batch

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I use a PreparedStatement and want to update a table.

I write it like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
   insertStatement.setString(1,"a");
   insertStatement.setString(2,"b");
   insertStatement.addBatch(); 
}

insertStatement.executeBatch();
```

I checked the records in DB, it is incremented one by one, not inserted as a 10000 rows batch.

As they are running as a batch, I think they should be inserted only when we call insertStatement.executeBatch();

However, it seems like every time I call insertStatement.addBatch() and one record is inserted into db;

Comment: There is nothing in the JDBC Javadoc that says it has be 'inserted as a 10000 rows batch'. The JDBC API defines what the JDBC driver does, not what the database server does.

Comment: @Jacky, Did you try `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` before starting the loop?
And at the end do `connection.commit()`?

Comment: I did not do anything special.

`try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test.batch_test(tst_value) VALUES (?)")) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pstmt.setDouble(1, Math.random() * 1000);
    pstmt.addBatch();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.asList(pstmt.executeBatch()));
  }`

I kept on refreshing the DB table, and after 10 seconds, all 10 records got inserted in one shot.  So, batch with MySQL Connector/J library works fine.

Comment: Thank you all! I found that it starts inserting when I call the execute command. I did not start a transaction,  so they are inserted one by one !